# Purpose of Seeding java.crypto.KeyGenerator

Tags: java, random, cryptography

Currently I am looking into using `javax.crypto.KeyGenerator` for API key/token generation, but looking at [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_cryptography/java_cryptography_keygenerator.htm) on its usage, the author calls the following:

```
SecureRandom secRandom = new SecureRandom();
keyGen.init(secRandom);
```

But when using the `KeyGenerator` it doesn't seem to produce repeats when not seeded when restarting the program, and the documentation says that "[KeyGenerator will use] a system-provided source of randomness if none of the installed providers supply a SecureRandom implementation". Is seeding it with a SecureRandom better in some way? Are system-provided sources of randomness often not cryptographically safe? And if not, what would SecureRandom use if not such an unsafe system-provided source of randomness?

Comment: Basically you can also call `KeyGen.init(int keySize);`, which will instantiate a `new SecureRandom();` internally. That's just an easy way to initialize it.

Comment: @Kayaman I have been using ```KeyGenerator.getInstance```, does it use an internal secure random too?

Comment: The [KeyGeneratorSpi](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyGeneratorSpi.html) instances take in `SecureRandom` parameters, but it's a bit hard to track down where those come from when calling `getInstance(String)`. Probably some service provider code calling `new SecureRandom();`. That site isn't known for its high quality tutorials either, just saying...